# Python: Permission error in shutil.move

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to copy/paste a directory with subdirs to a new destination. 
I only want files with the '.log' extension.

I see that some of the files and directories do in fact get moved but not the entire thing.

This is the code in question:

```
def copy_paste(self):

    src_dir = '/var/log/'
    dst_dir = '/home/user/Desktop/new_dir'
    for files in os.listdir(src_dir):
        if files.endswith('.log'):
            shutil.move(src_dir, dst_dir)
```

Error msg:

> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 555, in move
>      symlinks=True)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 359, in copytree
>       raise Error(errors)
>
> "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log.1.gz'"), ('/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log.1.gz', '/home/user/Desktop/new_dir/lightdm/lightdm.log.1.gz'

I have a bunch of these.

Comment: Read the error, what does it say?

Comment: Check you have permission to move these files

Comment: obviously i dont. how do i get around it

Comment: Well try the classic answer, use chmod

Comment: From your program, you don't get around it. The most you can do is have it start *another* program with correct permissions. As a user of this program, you get around it by ensuring you have required permissions prior to running the program. That may mean either changing the file permissions or running your program as root (after all you're deleting log files, that's an admin task).

Comment: spectras: thx, that make sense.. i just want to copy the files.. i dont want to delete them, tho..  like cp -R function in term..